# Firebase email verification and password reset uses project ID

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

i need some help with firebase hosting.

I have a website, for example, [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com). The Project ID is "mywebsite-v1", i gave this name not fully understanding the implications because its my first Firebase website.
The default domains according to Firebase hosting is "mywebsite-v1.web.app" and "mywebsite-v1.firebaseapp.com". I have connected my custom domains which are "mywebsite.com" and "www.mywebsite.com". So this is all fine, its not much of an issue.

The problem is that when a user is sent a verification email or a password reset email, the url that they are sent to is, for example: https:"//mywebsite-v1.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?..."

Which is what i have a problem with because i just want users to see [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com).

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/email-custom-domain?